# no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida «plaza» SQL state: 42830

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy creando una base de datos en PostgreSQL y me sale este error.

`no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida «plaza» SQL state: 4283`

```
CREATE DATABASE CONTROL_CFCRL;

CREATE TABLE plaza(
id_plaza SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
descripcion_plaza VARCHAR(100),
nivel_plaza INT,
sueldo_plaza FLOAT,
registro_alta DATE,
registro_cambio DATE,
registro_baja DATE,
habilitado boolean   
);

CREATE TABLE enlace(
id_enlace SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
descripcion_enlace VARCHAR(100),
id_plaza INT,
FOREIGN KEY (id_plaza) REFERENCES plaza(id_plaza),
registro_alta DATE,
FOREIGN KEY (registro_alta) REFERENCES plaza(registro_alta),
registro_cambio DATE,
FOREIGN KEY (registro_cambio) REFERENCES plaza(registro_cambio),    
registro_baja DATE,
FOREIGN KEY (registro_baja) REFERENCES plaza(registro_baja),
habilitado BOOLEAN,
FOREIGN KEY (habilitado) REFERENCES plaza(habilitado)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder definir una restricción de `FK`, debes tener en la tabla padre (plaza) una restricción de `PK` o al menos `UNIQUE`, en tu caso estas definiendo 5 FK y solo una de ellas (id_plaza) tiene restricción.

Pero en teoria relacional te bastaria con refereciar solo `id_plaza`, lo demás está reduntante, por ejemplo:

```sql
CREATE TABLE enlace(
id_enlace SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
descripcion_enlace VARCHAR(100),
id_plaza INT,
FOREIGN KEY (id_plaza) REFERENCES plaza(id_plaza)
);
```